# Hide an Html Element with a specific style via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, display, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to hide a specific type of element on a page. It is a div to which only the class "infocell" is assigned. There are about 30 elements per page. Some of the "infocell" divs have a green border. This is probably added via javascript, which I couldn't track down though.  So the elements look like this :

```html
<div class="infocell entry18764"></div>

<div class="infocell entry1178" style="border-top-color: rgb(0,153,51);">
</div>
```

EDIT: Html  From the Original Site

```html
<div class="infocell entry28056">
<a href="/info/28056#top" data-ajax="true"><img class="coverimage" src="//cdn.proxer.me/cover/28056.jpg">
</a>
<div>
<a href="/info/28056#top" data-ajax="true" style="font-size:17px;">
Majutsushi Orphen Hagure Tabi
</a>
<span style="display:block; font-size:10px;">
<a href="/info/28056#top" data-ajax="true">Details</a> - <a href="/info/28056/list#top" data-ajax="true">Liste</a>
</span>
</div>
<div>
Animeserie/TV <img class="tip" src="/images/status/abgeschlossen.png" title="Abgeschlossen" height="20">
</div>
<div>
Bewertung:5.73 (143)
</div>
<div style="border-bottom:0;">
Action Adventure Drama Fantasy Magic Martial-Art
</div>
</div>
<div class="infocell entry8862" style="border-top-color: rgb(0, 153, 51);">
<a href="/info/8862#top" data-ajax="true"><img class="coverimage" src="//cdn.proxer.me/cover/8862.jpg">
</a>
<div>
<a href="/info/8862#top" data-ajax="true" style="font-size:17px;">
Grisaia no Kajitsu
</a>
<span style="display:block; font-size:10px;">
<a href="/info/8862#top" data-ajax="true">Details</a> - <a href="/info/8862/list#top" data-ajax="true">Liste</a>
</span>
</div>
<div>
Animeserie/TV <img class="tip" src="/images/status/abgeschlossen.png" title="Abgeschlossen" height="20">
</div>
<div>
Bewertung:8.05 (4203)
</div>
<div style="border-bottom:0;">
Comedy Drama Ecchi Harem Mystery Psychological Romance School Seinen Violence
</div>
</div>
<div class="infocell entry24494">
<a href="/info/24494#top" data-ajax="true"><img class="coverimage" src="//cdn.proxer.me/cover/24494.jpg">
</a>
<div>
<a href="/info/24494#top" data-ajax="true" style="font-size:17px;">
Dakaretai Otoko 1-i ni Odosarete Imasu.
</a>
<span style="display:block; font-size:10px;">
<a href="/info/24494#top" data-ajax="true">Details</a> - <a href="/info/24494/list#top" data-ajax="true">Liste</a>
</span>
</div>
<div>
Animeserie/TV <img class="tip" src="/images/status/abgeschlossen.png" title="Abgeschlossen" height="20">
</div>
<div>
Bewertung:7.66 (353)
</div>
<div style="border-bottom:0;">
Comedy Drama Romance Shounen-Ai Smut Yaoi
</div>
</div>
<div class="infocell entry2080" style="border-top-color: rgb(0, 153, 51);">
<a href="/info/2080#top" data-ajax="true"><img class="coverimage" src="//cdn.proxer.me/cover/2080.jpg">
</a>
<div>
<a href="/info/2080#top" data-ajax="true" style="font-size:17px;">
Boku wa Tomodachi ga Sukunai
</a>
<span style="display:block; font-size:10px;">
<a href="/info/2080#top" data-ajax="true">Details</a> - <a href="/info/2080/list#top" data-ajax="true">Liste</a>
</span>
</div>
<div>
Animeserie/TV <img class="tip" src="/images/status/abgeschlossen.png" title="Abgeschlossen" height="20">
</div>
<div>
Bewertung:7.67 (8086)
</div>
<div style="border-bottom:0;">
Comedy Ecchi Harem Romance School Seinen Slice of Life
</div>
</div>
```

I couldn't find anything suitable for "hide element with a specific css style". I also have almost no idea about javascript but I tried the following:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("infocell");
  if (window.getComputedStyle(x).border-top-color === "rgb(0, 153, 51)") {
    document.getElementClassName("infocell").style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Of course this did not work.
I don't necessarily want to learn javascript just to solve this one problem. I hope one of you could help me with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append a `<style>` tag that selects elements with that particular style, and gives them `display: none`:

```js
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('style')).textContent = `
  [style="border-top-color: rgb(0,153,51);"] {
    display: none;
  }
`;
```

```html
<div class="infocell entry18764">content to remain</div>

<div class="infocell entry1178" style="border-top-color: rgb(0,153,51);">content to hide</div>
```

For the updated HTML, make sure the spacing in the selector string matches the spacing in the elements:

```js
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('style')).textContent = `
  [style="border-top-color: rgb(0, 153, 51);"] {
    display: none;
  }
`;
```

```html
<div class="infocell entry28056">
  <a href="/info/28056#top" data-ajax="true"><img class="coverimage" src="//cdn.proxer.me/cover/28056.jpg">
  </a>
  <div>
    <a href="/info/28056#top" data-ajax="true" style="font-size:17px;">
Majutsushi Orphen Hagure Tabi
</a>
    <span style="display:block; font-size:10px;">
<a href="/info/28056#top" data-ajax="true">Details</a> - <a href="/info/28056/list#top" data-ajax="true">Liste</a>
</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    Animeserie/TV <img class="tip" src="/images/status/abgeschlossen.png" title="Abgeschlossen" height="20">
  </div>
  <div>
    Bewertung:5.73 (143)
  </div>
  <div style="border-bottom:0;">
    Action Adventure Drama Fantasy Magic Martial-Art
  </div>
</div>
<div class="infocell entry8862" style="border-top-color: rgb(0, 153, 51);">
  <a href="/info/8862#top" data-ajax="true"><img class="coverimage" src="//cdn.proxer.me/cover/8862.jpg">
  </a>
  <div>
    <a href="/info/8862#top" data-ajax="true" style="font-size:17px;">
Grisaia no Kajitsu
</a>
    <span style="display:block; font-size:10px;">
<a href="/info/8862#top" data-ajax="true">Details</a> - <a href="/info/8862/list#top" data-ajax="true">Liste</a>
</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    Animeserie/TV <img class="tip" src="/images/status/abgeschlossen.png" title="Abgeschlossen" height="20">
  </div>
  <div>
    Bewertung:8.05 (4203)
  </div>
  <div style="border-bottom:0;">
    Comedy Drama Ecchi Harem Mystery Psychological Romance School Seinen Violence
  </div>
</div>
<div class="infocell entry24494">
  <a href="/info/24494#top" data-ajax="true"><img class="coverimage" src="//cdn.proxer.me/cover/24494.jpg">
  </a>
  <div>
    <a href="/info/24494#top" data-ajax="true" style="font-size:17px;">
Dakaretai Otoko 1-i ni Odosarete Imasu.
</a>
    <span style="display:block; font-size:10px;">
<a href="/info/24494#top" data-ajax="true">Details</a> - <a href="/info/24494/list#top" data-ajax="true">Liste</a>
</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    Animeserie/TV <img class="tip" src="/images/status/abgeschlossen.png" title="Abgeschlossen" height="20">
  </div>
  <div>
    Bewertung:7.66 (353)
  </div>
  <div style="border-bottom:0;">
    Comedy Drama Romance Shounen-Ai Smut Yaoi
  </div>
</div>
<div class="infocell entry2080" style="border-top-color: rgb(0, 153, 51);">
  <a href="/info/2080#top" data-ajax="true"><img class="coverimage" src="//cdn.proxer.me/cover/2080.jpg">
  </a>
  <div>
    <a href="/info/2080#top" data-ajax="true" style="font-size:17px;">
Boku wa Tomodachi ga Sukunai
</a>
    <span style="display:block; font-size:10px;">
<a href="/info/2080#top" data-ajax="true">Details</a> - <a href="/info/2080/list#top" data-ajax="true">Liste</a>
</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    Animeserie/TV <img class="tip" src="/images/status/abgeschlossen.png" title="Abgeschlossen" height="20">
  </div>
  <div>
    Bewertung:7.67 (8086)
  </div>
  <div style="border-bottom:0;">
    Comedy Ecchi Harem Romance School Seinen Slice of Life
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do i have to change anything about the code? i think i understand what it should do but it looks complete to me. I tried the code but nothing happens

Comment: No, the code is complete. Press "Run code snippet" and you will see it working as desired - the `content to hide` div gets hidden.

Comment: Hm maybe the javascript of the Site is "blocking it"? is there a way to force the code like in css with !important?

Comment: You could. If you're monkeypatching someone else's site, and you just want a quick solution that'll work I think `!important` is fine to use. Use `display: none !important;` instead of `display: none;`.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck. Yes I am trying to hide something on a foreign site. It is a library with series. The green border is a sign that I have already seen the series and the seen series I wanted to hide.   I used 2 plugins for firefox js and code injector. I entered the javascript code but unfortunately nothing happens. For control I also changed something in the css. This he has accepted without problems

Thats how the source text looks like: https://imgur.com/doqvJY4

Comment: I am using the exact same HTML code you have in the question, and as you can see with the snippet, it works fine, given your code. If the code in the answer doesn't work for you, then the code you're actually dealing with must be different. Can you update the question with the actual code of the site?

Comment: Okay i copied a snippet of the html of the Site in the Main Question

Comment: The spacing in the attribute string on the page is different from what you had posted originally, which was why it was failing. `rgb(0,153,51);` is not the same as `rgb(0, 153, 51);`

Comment: oh jesus! well i didn't know that  but yes im kind of slow. But now i works!  i have this problem for like 8 years and finally! Really big thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the specific class on a div.

```
const divTochange = document.querySelector('div');
divTochange.classList.contains('class you want to filter');
```

Comment: Hm i dont understand that =/. i can't filter by class. The divs i want to see and the divs i want to hide have the same class